# How to get object passed into view from Node for use in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

node

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', { authUser : req.user });
});
```

angular

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = authUser; // from the view
}
```

I need access to the authUser in the Angular code. I'm familiar with using $http.get to get data from a res.json(...), but am not sure how to do it in this scenario.

Comment: `res.json(req.user)`?

Comment: I agree with Ben, another option if you are using cookies could be this one http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2013/08/01/how-to-read-the-play-session-from-angularjs/

Comment: I also need the res.render to display the view though. Is there a way both res.json to get the data and res.render for the rest of the view?

Answer (score 0):

res.render is only sending the authUser to the EJS view engine, not back to the client. If you only need to display the user info then you can add something like <%= authUser.displayName %> to profile.ejs.